# issue with Spring.AjaxEventDecoration and dijit.form.Select in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dojo, spring-webflow

I am having a issue with using Spring.AjaxEventDecoration and  dijit.form.Select, if the user picks the sex type from the select box somehow I am getting the elementID in the bean is Spring MVC?  Below is my form:

```
<form:select path="sex">
<form:option value="MALE" label="MALE" />
<form:option value="FEMALE" label="FEMALE" />
</form:select> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
  elementId : "sex",
  widgetType : "dijit.form.Select",
  widgetAttrs : {
  promptMessage : "Enter Sex",
  required : true }}));

  Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
  elementId: "sex",
  event: "onChange",
  formId:"customer",
  params: {fragments:"body", _eventId: "loadSchools"}}));
</script>
```

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859099/issue-with-springs-web-flow-form-submit-values-are-right-ajaxeventdecoration-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.  I removed the ***Spring.AjaxEventDecoration*** call and changed the ***Spring.ElementDecoration*** to the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
                                elementId : "sex",
                                widgetType : "dijit.form.Select",
                                widgetAttrs : {
                                promptMessage : "Enter Sex",
                                required : true, 
                                onChange : function() {
                                    Spring.remoting.submitForm(
                                        'submit', 
                                        'customer', 
                                        {_eventId: 'sexchange', fragments:'contents'}
                                     ); 
                                     return false;
                                } }}));


                        </script>
```

I am not 100% clear on why the Ajax call did not work but I have my project working with this code now!